# How type superscript text in OpenERP textbox & Save into DB

Tags: python, xml, odoo

let me know the way to handle this: I need to type `Superscript` text in `OpenERP` text box & Need to save into `postgresDB`.

Comment: OR - Let me know How to convert a string to Superscript - in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTML field for that content: they support rich text formatting, including superscript.

```
my_field = fields.Html()
```